# How do I parse JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm working on a little economics project in Java and looking for somebody who's worked with JSON before to help me overcome my current hurdle.

I have a real-time JSON database with thousands of elements that each have buy and sell prices.

http://www.rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json

Below is the first of the elements from that JSON

```
"2": {
    "overall_average": 198,
    "buy_average": 197,
    "id": 2,
    "sp": 5,
    "sell_average": 199,
    "members": true,
    "name": "Cannonball"
}
```

What I'd like to do is have a little Java code that runs through all of the elements and returns only the elements with a 'buy/sell margin' 
(so 'buy_average' minus 'sell_average') that is greater than 1,000.

Comment: consider [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or another JSON serializer/deserializer, to convert your json to java objects. As you have converted your json, process the data inside of your objects as you want.

Comment: 1) This isn't a forum 2) This isn't a "hire a coder to do this for me" site

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Gson.

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
. . . 
        Gson GSON = new Gson();
         List<Map<String, Object>> search = ...
            String json = GSON.toJson(search);
```

it's a very intuitive utility...

heres the maven ref

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```